# SaltStack diff of minion state using Python

Tags: python, salt-stack

I am writing custom wrapper for SaltStack in python, I couldn't figure from the Salt documentation any way that I can get the diff of state of a minion.

What I mean is when we run the state from CLI, it shows the diff in different colors and I am trying to show only the difference, not the whole.

CLI command:

```
salt '*' state.highstate test=True
```

I figured from CLI it is possible using `--state-verbose=False`, is there any way to use the same flag with Python?

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for the history of changes and want to store them in a database?

The matching page is this: https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/jobs/job_cache.html

> The Salt Master maintains a job cache of all job executions which can be queried via the jobs runner. This job cache is called the Default Job Cache.

AFAIK there is no easy way to get a nice GUI which shows you the changes which are done during the last time.

Comment: I am looking to see the changes which will be done after I run..

salt '*' state.highstate test=False

I can run like 

salt '*' state.highstate test=True --state-verbose=False

I can use python subprocess module but Is there any way to replicate above command using Salt Python Api?

Answer (score 0):

Using the python client, you can just add "test=true" as a kwarg to your localclient.cmd().

https://docs.saltstack.com/en/2015.8/ref/clients/index.html#salt-s-client-interfaces

Does that solve the issue? If you need an example, I'll add one as soon as I get to my laptop.